# -bash: /usr/local/bin/php: operation not permitted

Tags: php, permissions

Why I am unable to execute any command that requires php. For instance

```
[root@server ~]# composer -V
"/usr/bin/env: php: Operation not permitted"
```

Here is the permission on where composer is installed:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 220 Dec 5 03:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 267 Dec 3 05:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2200574 Dec 5 03:39 composer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49732288 Dec 3 05:14 lsphp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 817 Nov 27 23:56 pear
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 838 Nov 27 23:56 peardev
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 751 Nov 27 23:56 pecl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 3 05:15 phar -> phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14817 Dec 3 05:15 phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49826928 Dec 3 05:14 php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49668664 Dec 3 05:14 php-cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3574 Dec 3 05:15 php-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50757280 Dec 3 05:14 phpdbg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4563 Dec 3 05:15 phpize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24336 Dec 3 05:11 zipcmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18824 Dec 3 05:11 zipmerge
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34880 Dec 3 05:11 ziptool
```

Comment: That output does not look real. It looks like the output of several different commands was pasted together. Please post the actual command you ran and its actual output.

Comment: @Michael Hampton
the exact output i get running composer -V gives me just this message: "/usr/bin/env: php: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Not that, the other command(s).

Comment: What does`which php` say?

Comment: which php gives: /usr/local/bin/php
@andrew-schulman